# What is the default buffer size of AVPlayer?

Tags: buffer, avplayer

What is the default maximum and minimum buffer size of iOS AVPlayer? How to increasing its size for mp3 streaming? thank you

Comment: Did you get the answer? I'm also searching for it, but till now I haven't found any solution. If you find any answer, please post it here.

Answer (score 2):

If your **buffer size** means playback buffer, then I believe this size is undocumented.

This behaviour is provided by AVFoundation, quoted on [Advances in AVFoundation Playback](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/503/)

> And we see that playback starts but then we quickly run into a stall because we didn't have enough buffer to play to the end.
>
> In that case, we'll go into the waiting state and re-buffer until we have enough to play through.

They just mentioned **enough** not the exact time or size, it make sense that is a dynamic unit of measurement according to current network situation, but who knows.

Back to the topic, if you would like to take control of buffering.
You can observe `AVPlayerItem`'s `loadedTimeRanges` property.

below code snippet had 5 seconds buffer time:

```c
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"loadedTimeRanges"]) {
    
    NSArray *timeRanges = (NSArray *)[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
    if (timeRanges && [timeRanges count]) {
        CMTimeRange timerange = [[timeRanges objectAtIndex:0] CMTimeRangeValue];
        
        if (self.audioPlayer.rate == 0 && !pauseReasonForced) {
            CMTime bufferdTime = CMTimeAdd(timerange.start, timerange.duration);
            CMTime milestone = CMTimeAdd(self.audioPlayer.currentTime, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5.0f, timerange.duration.timescale));
            
            if (CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(bufferdTime , >, milestone) && self.audioPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay && !interruptedWhilePlaying && !routeChangedWhilePlaying) {
                if (![self isPlaying]) {
                    
                    [self.audioPlayer play];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```